# Rstudio console shortcut

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I updated my Rstudio to Version: 2023.03.1+446

When I press `ALT + LEFT ARROW` to get to the start of the line in the console, instead of letting me stay and edit what I have in the console, it now selects the `FILE` tab on the top left of the IDE.
I have to keep moving back to my console either with `CTRL + 2` or with my mouse.

It is annoying.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I also encountered this recently, and I'll just `ALT` again to un-select the file tab (it's weird that Rstudio keyboard shortcut do not have an option for this)